# Storing the binaries of my software by versions in central location

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, tfs, nuget, assemblies

I would like to have my software versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.3 etc to be stored centrally. The idea behind this is to have an AppDomain sprung up with the right version of the dlls (so if they are asked to use version 1.2 and they don't have it, then they can download it from the central repository).

From what I've seen, there are too many options to solve this:
1) storing the binaries myself in S3
2) using TFS (visual studio online CI or some sort of it)
3) private Nuget server hosting packages of different versions.
4) other options I haven't thought of yet

I would like to hear in which direction you would choose, or any other tips

Thanks

Comment: If you're already using VSO/VS Team Services and you're in the US region, there's a public preview of a package management service.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to store the different version flies of your software, then you only need a file server such as private Nuget server you mentioned.

If you need **completely version control** which mean including the management of changes to documents, computer programs, web sites, and other collections of information. I suggest you use the professional ALM tools like TFS/VSO. It will help you standardize your project. It will also improve the cooperation among teams. 
Moreover , this is just not only including version control. There are many other great things in TFS, such as test, project management ,release management and so on.